# Cannot group and total csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I created a csv file with two columns author and number of books - see sample (apologies could not below to look like a table but column 1 has author and column two just has number 1 in this illustration)

```
Vincent 1
Vincent 1
Vincent 1
Vincent 1
Thomas  1
Thomas  1
Thomas  1
Jimmy   1
Jimmy   1
```

I am trying to create an output csv which sums books by author ie Vincent 5, Thomas 3 and Jimmy 2

Using code below I managed to get to the intermediate stage where I got a cumulative total for each author.  The line `print line[0], countAuthor` produces which is fine

```
Vincent 1
Vincent 2
Vincent 3
Vincent 4
Thomas  1
Thomas  2
Thomas  3
Jimmy   1
Jimmy   2
```

I had then planned to take this output into a list, sort it descending and keep only the record with highest value i.e. where current author is same as previous author then skip - I would then write output into another csv file

My problem is that I cannot write the author and the cumulative total into a list - I can get it into variable w.  `print w[2]` works but `print data[2]` does not as it appears that data only has one column. Any help will be much appreciated as I have spent nearly two days on this without much luck - I am forced to use csv as the full file has author names with blank spaces etc

```
with open("testingtesting6a.csv") as inf:
data = []
author = 'XXXXXXXX'
countAuthor = 0.0
for line in inf:
    line = line.split(",")
    if line[0] == author:
        countAuthor = countAuthor + float(line[1])
    else:
        countAuthor = float(line[1])
        author = line[0]

    # print line[0], countAuthor

    w = (line[0],line[1],countAuthor)
    print w[2]
    data.append(w)
    print data[2]
    # print data[0]
    # print type(w)
    # print w[2]
```

Comment: Can you show an example of data that you want to print? Because the way I see it, you want something like {'Vincent': 5, 'Thomas': 3, 'Jimmy': 2}

Comment: what do you expect to be printed by `print data[2]` ?

Answer (score 0):

The standard library already has this covered.

```
import collections

def sum_up(input_file):
    counter = collections.defaultdict(int)
    for line in input_file:
        parts = line.split()  # splits by any whitespace.
        if len(parts) != 2:
          continue  # skip the line that does not parse; maybe a blank line.
        name, number = parts
        counter[name] += int(number)  # you can't borrow 1.25 books.
    return counter
```

Now you can:

```
with open('...') as f:
  counts = sum_up(f)

for name, count in sorted(counts.items()):
  print name, count  # prints counts sorted by name.

print counts['Vincent']  # prints 4.

print counts['Jane']  # prints 0.
```

The trick here is the use of [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), a dict that pretends to have a value for any key. We ask it to have a default value generated by `int()`, which is 0.

Comment: Thanks for that folks - I tried what you suggested 9000.  When I got to the name, number = linesplit() I got an error message "Value error need more than one value to unpack"

Comment: Do you have lines that don't contain exactly two values in them? The assignment assumes there'll be exactly two. See the update.

Answer (score 0):

### Removing spaces with `strip`, groupby with Pandas:

Input file (adtional spaces are intentional):

```
author,books
Vincent, 1
Vincent , 1
Vincent, 1
Vincent, 1
Thomas  ,  1
Thomas,  1
Thomas,  1
Jimmy,   1
Jimmy  ,   1

import csv
import pandas as pd

fin = open('author.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(fin, delimiter=',')

# strip remove spaces
authors=[( (d['author']).strip(), int((d['books']).strip())) for d in reader]

df = pd.DataFrame(authors)
df.columns = ['author', 'books']
df2 = (df.groupby('author').sum())
print (df2)    

         books
author        
Jimmy        2
Thomas       3
Vincent      4

# For total of books:
print (df2.books.sum())
9
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me folks i entered print data[2] just to prove to myself that data did not have 3 columns data[2] returned index error - re expected output i wanted to have Vincent,4 and Thomas,3 and James,4